# Postfix - Allow authenticated connections on encrypted connection only

Tags: postfix

I currently have Postfix setup to deliver mail to local users without authenticating (to receive incoming email from other SMTP servers for my local users), and with SASL so my users can authenticate in order to relay mail through my system.  I'm setup to accept connections on port 25 (plain text) and 465 (SSL).

Currently, a local user is allowed to connect to either port and authenticate.  I would like to limit authentication to only port 465, so that any connections coming into port 25 can't authenticate, and thus can only send email to local users.  The purpose is two-fold:

- To prevent users from being able to send their username and password
  in plain-text.
- To help alleviate automated bot attacks that connect on port 25 and
  attempt to authenticate by making this impossible.

Comment: Also connections on port 25 can be encrypted by using the `STARTTLS` SMTP command.

Comment: BTW port 465 is unofficial and not associated with SMTP(S) for a long time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796530/what-is-the-difference-between-ports-465-and-587

Comment: @Marki555, thanks for that bit of info. While not an official standard, it certainly is a de-facto one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- *To prevent users from being able to send their username and password in plain-text.*

Use this in `main.cf`:

```
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
```

- *To help alleviate automated bot attacks that connect on port 25 and attempt to authenticate by making this impossible.*

Use this in `master.cf`:

```
smtps inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
```

Comment: I already have the settings you mentioned in `master.cf`, that's how I'm doing SSL now. But adding `smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes` to `main.cf` took care of it and gives me the results I'm looking for. Thanks!